# Saving data in multiple android activities

Tags: android

I wanted to know how one can save data on multiple activities during navigation.

I have 2 forms in my application, `account details` and `personal details`, each on its own activity. When the user clicks a `next` button in the `account details` activity, it takes him to the `personal details` activity. The `personal details` activity also has a back button to take the user back to the `account details` activity.

What I want is that when the user clicks the `next` button, it will save the data in the `account details` activity so that it may be displayed when the user returns to the `account details` activity. Also, when the user enters data in the `personal details` activity and probably moves back to the `account details` activity by clicking `back`, the data in the `personal details` activity should be saved so that when the user moves again to the `personal details` activity, he may find his data.

What I have done is override the `onActivityResult` method and added some methods to save data in the `account details` activity as shown:

```
package com.example.karyukie.application;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AccountDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText usernameSignUp, newPwd, confirmPwd, securityA;
Spinner securityQ;

private static final String USERNAME_SIGN_UP = "usernameSignUp_key";
private static final String PWD_SIGN_UP = "pwdSignUp_key";
private static final String SECURITY_Q = "securityQ_key";
private static final String SECURITY_A = "securityA_key";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    usernameSignUp =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameSignUp_editText);
    newPwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPwd_editText);
    confirmPwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmPwd_editText);
    securityQ = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.securityQ_spinner);
    securityA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.securityA_editText);

    securityQ.setSelection(9);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    assert next != null;
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle accountDetails_data = saveData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PersonalDetails.class);
                intent.putExtras(accountDetails_data);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
    });

public Bundle saveData() {
    String usernameSignUp_value = usernameSignUp.getText().toString();
    String pwdSignUp_value = newPwd.getText().toString();
    int securityQ_value = securityQ.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String securityA_value = securityA.getText().toString();

    Bundle data = new Bundle();

    data.putString(USERNAME_SIGN_UP, usernameSignUp_value);
    data.putString(PWD_SIGN_UP, pwdSignUp_value);
    data.putInt(SECURITY_Q, securityQ_value);
    data.putString(SECURITY_A, securityA_value);

    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            usernameSignUp.setText(data.getStringExtra(USERNAME_SIGN_UP));
            newPwd.setText(data.getStringExtra(PWD_SIGN_UP));
            confirmPwd.setText(data.getStringExtra(PWD_SIGN_UP));
            securityQ.setSelection(data.getIntExtra(SECURITY_Q, 10));
            securityA.setText(data.getStringExtra(SECURITY_A));
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `personal details` activity:

```
Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    assert back != null;
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtras(data);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

It seems to work fine but I cannot figure how to save the data in the `personal details` activity as earlier described.

Comment: Intents are good for sending data between activities, but there are more options for persistent storage across your whole app. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to pass data using Intents. You can also use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to share data between activities.

You can get a preferences object by calling:

`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences();`

Then (to use String data as an example) store using:

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("key", "value").apply();
```

and get data using:

```
sharedPreferences.getString("key", "default_value");
```

Comment: @brayokaris While I agree that this answer should contain code, you could also follow the link to find how to store and load the data...

Comment: @brayokaris Please see my edit. Although I would suggest you take the time to read through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks back from the account details to the personal, you don't have to save data if you did not already finish the personal details activity, and vice versa.

You can save data on public static variables. This is the easiest way, you also can transfer data with the intents between activities.